# Handling overinput with scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

With scanf() I would like to make sure that nothing more than what exactly the format says isn't inputted. My code:

```
if (scanf("< %ld ; %ld > %c", &lo, &hi, &control) == 3)
    {

    }
```

I am scanning input of the form `<0;100> s` and would like to make sure noone is able to enter something like `<0;100> sasdf` (representing an interval), in this case scanf() says this is ok, because it did 3 succesfull conversions and not throw err. I really only want to scan that one char after the interval. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I [agree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53146970/204883) that it's better to use `fgets` to read line-by-line into a buffer and parse the buffer, instead of using `scanf` directly on `stdin`. In particular, `scanf` leaves unread input that may then cause problems in unrelated places trying to read something else.

However, if you are set on `scanf`, it seems you might want something like:

```
if (scanf("< %ld ; %ld > %c%1[^\n ]%*[^\n ]", &lo, &hi, &control, &control) == 3)
```

That is, try to read a single non-space and non-newline character after the control character. If that succeeds, it returns `4` instead of `3`, causing the `== 3` comparison to be false. The suppressed (`*`) input at the end then consumes any non-newline and non-space input.

Note that this leaves any trailing newline unconsumed, you need to account for that in any future input, including before retrying with this same pattern.

Comment: Note: this is based on a now-deleted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53146933/204883) that proposed the same idea but was deleted by the author before completion.

Answer (score 2):

Read the input as a line using e.g. `fgets()`. Then use `sscanf()` to try and parse it:

```
char  buffer[1024];
char *line;
long  lo, hi;
char  control, dummy;

line = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
if (!line) {
    /* No input at all. */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (sscanf(line, " < %ld ; %ld > %c %c", &lo, &hi, &control, &dummy) == 3) {
    /* Format is good, we have lo, hi, and control. */
} else {
    /* Not this format; complain. */
}
```

Note that the final `%c` should be preceded by a space; that way any trailing whitespace, including newlines, are consumed prior to the final `%c`. Essentially, it is a dummy conversion that does not happen when the format is correct; that is also why we expect a result of 3 and not 4. When the result is 3, we know the first three conversions were successful, but the fourth dummy one was not, and that obviously means the input was formatted correctly, in the desired pattern, without anything else on the line.

This way, you can also support multiple different formats at the same time. For example,

```
if (sscanf(line, " < %ld ; %ld > %c %c", &lo, &hi, &control, &dummy) == 3 ||
    sscanf(line, " ( %ld %1*[,;] %ld ) %c %c", &lo, &hi, &control, &dummy) == 3 ||
    sscanf(line, " %ld %ld %c %c", &lo, &hi, &control, &dummy) == 3) {
    /* Format is good, we have lo, hi, and control. */
} else {
    /* Not this format; complain. */
}
```

accepts for example `<1;2>x`, `< 1 ; 2 > x`, `(3,4)y`, `(5;6)z`, `7+8w` and `9 10 c`.

The `%1*[,;]` part is funky: the `1` says that at most one character is accepted. The asterisk `*` says it does not count as a conversion (in the return value), and it is not stored (so there is no corresponding parameter). The `[` type modifier character specifies a list of accepted (or rejected, if `^` is the first character) characters, until `]`. So, in English, we might describe it thus: *"accept one comma or a semicolon, but don't count it as a conversion or store it"*. (If it was `%3*[,;/]`, then it would be *"accept between one to three characters, where each character is a comma, semicolon, or a slash"*. Very useful for this kind of cases.)

Comment: we actually want that `%c` aswell

Comment: @MichalDvořák: Added it into the pattern.

Comment: @MichalDvořák Even though you've accepted my answer, I strongly suggest that you adapt the `fgets` + `sscanf` pattern of this answer instead. You can still take the format string from my answer if this didn't work for you. Using `scanf` on `stdin` is really fragile, e.g., consider partial inputs like `<0` and `<0;100>`, or multiple extra fields like `<0;100> s foo bar`. Can you recover from all of those? With `fgets` it's trivial to discard the entire line.